# Windows Defender: Saving settings shows error: "No such interface supported"

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, visual-studio-2010, windows-defender

Windows Defender can no longer save settings. It's stuck at scanning all the time, the entire drive, and when the smallest file is downloaded.
This is a slow-down in Visual Studio, Google Chrome etc. because it raises disk usage to 100% for 15-35 minutes after I hit 'close' on the application and it starts to scan every single file (In resource monitor appears that 24/7 it's scanning drivers, Chrome, Visual Studio folders).
I tried to exclude these folders, what I get is this error message:

[image: Windows Defender Error 0x80004002]

How to fix this without a reinstall?

P.S.: Topics for "Explorer.exe No such interface supported" does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing Microsoft Security Essentials instead. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14210/security-essentials-download